# How to (1) get selected value from Angular/Bootstrap dropdown and (2) show selected choice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get Angular-UI dropdown to work:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

1. How do I pass the value to my Angular function so I can process it?
2. How can I display the selected choice after the user selects it instead of always showing "Please Select:"

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1Vz8T4NMi39JpdSdXgFd

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
          type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="toggled">Please Select:
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
            <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="choice in items">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{choice}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DropdownCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {

    $scope.items = ['one','two','three','four'];

    $scope.toggled = function(value) {
        alert('the value you chose was ' + value)
    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, modify the code related to the dropdown to add binding to the text displayed in the dropdown (via `ng-bind`) + execute a function when an element in the dropdown is clicked (via `ng-click`) :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
      type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="toggled" ng-bind='selected'>Tutorials
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="choice in items">
            <a role="menuitem" ng-click="setTutorial(choice)" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{choice}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in the javascript, add this function which is executed when an element in the dropdown is clicked:

```
$scope.selected = "Tutorial";
$scope.setTutorial = function(value) {
  $scope.selected = value;
}
```

With this function, you can:
1. get the value of the item which is clicked
2. update the selected choice.

Answer (score 6):

For Angular 4 with Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6, here's a tip on how you could do this:

**HTML for Bootstrap dropdown control**

```
       <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label">Account</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
              <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
                {{selectedValue}} <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li *ngFor="let account of accounts" value="{{account._id}}" (click)="selectValue(account)"
                    class="dropdown-item">{{account.firstname}} {{account.lastname}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**JS Component Code**

```
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {
   selectedValue: string = '-- select value --';
   selectedId: string;

   // On-Click Method on dropdown control
   selectValue(account: Account) {
      this.selectedValue = account.firstname + ' ' + account.lastname;
      this.selectedId = account._id;
   }
}
```